# input resistance of differential amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, differential

[image]
i have a question about the differential amplifier 
i know that the input resistance for the common mode is

Rin = rpi + 2 Beta Ree / 2 
but my question is what is the input resistance for the differential signal ? 
this is the small signal equivalent circuit 
[image]

Comment: Input impedance (I'm not saying resistance as there are capacitors as well) is a **small signal property** so **draw the small signal equivalent circuit** and then start your analysis.

Comment: this is the small signal equivalent ciruict that i used but i couldn't determine Rin

Comment: Have a look at: http://metalab.uniten.edu.my/~jamaludin/EEEB273%20N05-%20Diff%20Amp%20BJT%20x6.pdf

Comment: @Gh-B Please read Bimpelrekkie's link. Good information there, if you search through it.

Answer (score 1):

I think, this question needs - at first - some definitions.

(1) Common mode is clearly defined: \$V_{b1} = V_{b2}\$

(2) Unsymmetrical diff. mode: \$V_{b1}\$ finite and \$V_{b2} = 0\$.

(3) Symmetrical diff. mode: \$V_{b2} = -V_{b1}\$

(4) General symm. mode: \$V_{b1}\$ finite and \$V_{b2}\$ finite (with \$V_{b1} \ne V_{b2}\$).

**Input resistances**: For the first three cases, it is a relatively simple task to find the dynamic input resistances \$r_{in}\$ (here given at the base of Q1)

Case (1): \$ r_{in} = r_\pi + \beta\cdot 2 r_e \$ (re: diff. resistance of the common emitter path) .

Case (2): \$ r_{in} = 2 r_\pi \$

Case (3): \$ r_{in} = r_\pi \$

Case (4): The input resistance at the base of Q1 depends on the signal \$V_{b2}\$ which is applied at the base of Q2. There is no textbook which gives an expression for the input resistance in this case (as far as I know). In this case, the input resistance must be calculated using superposition of the two cases (1) and (3). This is because each arbitrary combination of \$V_{b1}\$ and \$V_{b2}\$ can be split into the cases (1) and (3).

As the result, the formula for the input resistance will contain (and, thus, depend on) both input signals! Therefore, no compact expression can be given.

Comment: can u please explain a little more i'm not sure that i understand the four cases u talked about

Comment: I don`t know what to furhter explain. The 4 cases are definitions for the 4 possible different combinatons of Vb1 and Vb2.

Comment: Wants to know how to compute Rpi.

Comment: If case 2 (being one specific example of case 4) can be analyzed as a superposition of cases 1 and 3, why doesn't \$\beta\$ appear in the expression for \$r_{\pi}\$ there?

Comment: I do not understand the two last comments. I did not speak about the method how to find rpi. That is a complete other question. Of course, rpi depends on beta and the corresponding DC current Ic (rpi=beta*Vt/Ic). Something wrong in my answer?

Comment: i mean what i understand is that the input resistance of the differential mode depends on the cases of the inputs .1) if vb1 = vb2 means there is no differential voltage then Rin = rpi + beta*2Re.2) if one of the input voltages is 0 and the other is not then Rin = 2rpi . 3)if vb2 = _vb1 means that they are equal in magnitude but opposite in polarity then Rin = rpi . 4)which is i wanna know u say there is no specific eqyation to follow but if i use superposition then by applying vb1,kill vb2 & solve for Rin i'll have one of the half circuits as common emitter & the other as common gate

Comment: and Rin for CE = rpi and Rin for Cg = re = vt / Ie then wouldn't Rin be equal to the sum of these two input resistors looking at each input ?

Comment: and i don't understand why in the second case rin = 2rpi ? as i said if vb2 = 0 then Q2 is a Cg amplifier and its input resistance = re so why is it 2 rpi ?

Comment: Correct - the input resistance of the CG stage is rin,2=re=1/gm2. This resistance works as a feedback resistance for the first CE stage. And the feedback factor is (1+gm1*rin2)=(1+gm1/gm2) = 2. Therefore, we have rin1=rpi*2.

Comment: Regarding case (4): As you have seen, the input resistance at Q1 depends on the input at Q2. For some special cases (1, 2 and 3) it is possible to find relatively simple expressions - however, for arbritrary inputs at Q2, the calculation is not as simple  as in cases (1)...(3). We need superposion of cases (1) and (3).